# How do I connect to my Apache server located on my guest VM?

Tags: networking, windows, apache-httpd, vmware

I run windows 10 on my host machine and through VMWare recently installed a CentOS version of Linux and installed an Apache server. On the host I'm able to access the server via 'localhost' or entering the IP address of the machine. However, when I try to access the server on my host machine it says the site can't be reached.

And the workbench VM settings I do have the network adapter set to Bridged, but I still cannot access the server through my host. I have tried pinging the IP address of my guest machine from my host and it does seem to send/receive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not 100% sure if I'm connecting to the right IP address from my host, but I found the IP address through `ifconfig` and plucked the inet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll post my solution in case others come across the same problem. But essentially the firewall on my guest machine didn't have the appropriate port open, which in this case is port 80.
[I found the solution here.](http://www.putorius.net/2011/05/basic-of-iptables-opening-ports-on.html)